# IOS: organize UIButton spaces

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have three button in my view and sometimes I should hide one button or two button because I don't use them; I can insert them in a toolbar or in a subview but I don't know a fast solution to fair distance buttons. For example:

Three buttons:

[image]

Two button:

[image]

One button:

[image]

is there a fast solution to distance button in a dynamic solution, without take their position?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: finally I use a stati method to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
float width = 768.0f;
int numberOfButtons = 3;
float buttonWidth = 100.0f;
float buttonHeight = 40.0f;

float spaceX = floorf((width - (numberOfButtons * buttonWidth)) / (numberOfButtons + 1));

float x,y,w,h;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
{
    x = spaceX + (spaceX * i);
    y = 100.0f;
    w = buttonWidth;
    h = buttonHeight;

    UIButton * b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
}
```

Where `width` is the gray view.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a UICollectionView. It would allow you to dynamically add and remove buttons and it would handle all appropriate layout.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. UICollectionview would easily and reliably solve the exact problem he is asking about.